# Expressing statements in Discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given that

$A$ is the set of all Alpha's

$M$ is the set of all Men

how do I express this statement: Not all Alpha's are Men

.............

My attempt:

$A \subset S = 0$

in other words saying that $A$ is not a subset of $S$,
but I can't use the not subset symbol on this problem.

Comment: $\exists a\in A:a\notin M$

Comment: What is $S$?  Did you mean $A \subset M = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write $A\backslash M\ne\emptyset$.

Meaning that when you take all the men out of the alphas, there are alphas remaining.

Comment: the \ is the difference symbol ? It makes a lot more sense this way, Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It is equivalent to A\cap M^c. M^c being the complement.

Answer (score 1):

"not all alpha's are men" $\Leftrightarrow$"there is an alpha who is not a man".

i.e.

$$ \exists a \in A \text{ such that } a \not\in M $$

Comment: I like the way you reworded it, makes it a lot more easier to express